# Controlling positive and negative voltage rail

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, gate-driving

[image]

I need to control and switch between positive and negative voltage rail at about 400 kHz with PWM signal at 50% duty cycle(Square wave). The positive rail is at about 150V and negative at -50V. It is possible to switch just positive rail but I'm not able to do for the negative rail. I've tried to use MOSFETs with gate drivers but I can't seem to get it work. Can any one suggest a schematic for this?

Comment: What's your schematic?

Comment: Simplify: PWM signal at 50% duty cycle = square wave. Your requirement is not easily achieved if you want the output to have significantly low rise and fall times.

Comment: @Swedgin I don't have one that works for negative rail but for positive rail this should work (Added to the question)

Comment: The problem is the negative rail and 400KHz switching. although 400Khz can be achieved easily it's hard to handle negative rail. Can you tell how much is your voltage for gate drivers referenced to negative rail??

Comment: @Deepak : PWM is an output from a microcontroller which is 0 to 3V3(This can be varied to 5V, if neccesary)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a Mosfet Gate driver with an isolated Gate driving transformer.**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVLg7b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is not the actual circuit but the idea how you can do this!